# Memory leak in a node.js crawler application

Tags: node.js

For over a month I'm struggling with a very annoying memory leak issue and I have no clue how to solve it.

I'm writing a general purpose web crawler based on: http, async, cheerio and nano. From the very beginning I've been struggling with memory leak which was very difficult to isolate. 
I know it's possible to do a heapdump and analyse it with Google Chrome but I can't understand the output. It's usually a bunch of meaningless strings and objects leading to some anonymous functions telling me exactly nothing (it might be lack of experience on my side).

Eventually I came to a conclusion that the library I had been using at the time (jQuery) had issues and I replaced it with Cheerio. I had an impression that Cheerio solved the problem but now I'm sure it only made it less dramatic.

You can find my code at: https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/node-web-crawler. I understand it might be lots of code to analyse but perhaps I'm doing something stupid which can be obvious strait away. I'm suspecting the main agent class which does HTTP requests https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/node-web-crawler/blob/master/webcrawler/agent.js from multiple "threads" (with `async.queue`).

If you would like to run the code it requires CouchDB and after `npm install` do:

`$ node crawler.js -c conf.example.json`

I know that Node doesn't go crazy with garbage collection but after 10min of heavy crawling used memory can go easily over 1GB.

(tested with v0.10.21 and v0.10.22)

Comment: You saved me with this sentence: "This is a tiny memory leak on its own but insignificant. The strange thing is that the string is somehow related to the whole HTML object and keeps reference to it.". I've spent three full days trying to find what was leaking in my code and I discovered that it was related to an array of URLs. Then I saw this post and tried to break the references using a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))`. My memory leak instantly and magically went away. I wished I'd seen this post earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, Node's memory usage will grow and grow even if your actual used memory isn't very large.  This is for optimization on behalf of the V8 engine.  To see your real memory usage (to determine if there is actually a memory leak) consider dropping this code (or something like it) into your application:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (typeof gc === 'function') {
        gc();
    }
    applog.debug('Memory Usage', process.memoryUsage());
}, 60000);
```

Run `node --expose-gc yourApp.js`.  Every minute there will be a log line indicating real memory usage immediately after a forced garbage collection.  I've found that watching the output of this over time is a good way to determine if there is a leak.

If you do find a leak, the best way I've found to debug it is to eliminate large sections of your code at a time.  If the leak goes away, put it back and eliminate a smaller section of it.  Use this method to narrow it down to where the problem is occurring.  Closures are a common source, but also check for anywhere else references may not be cleaned up.  Many network applications will attach handlers for sockets that aren't immediately destroyed.

Comment: FYI. The problem is definitely there: { rss: 134713344, heapTotal: 94329600, heapUsed: 27132928 }
{ rss: 226758656, heapTotal: 180926016, heapUsed: 109045368 }
{ rss: 296513536, heapTotal: 253418872, heapUsed: 140803152 }
{ rss: 311947264, heapTotal: 264942592, heapUsed: 147487528 }
{ rss: 354574336, heapTotal: 294030992, heapUsed: 190165824 }
{ rss: 487866368, heapTotal: 412446680, heapUsed: 220472240 }

Comment: @LukaszKujawa you can also check out memwatch. https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I think I got to the bottom of the issue. It's quite strange and I'm not sure is that a bug or feature. I store all URLs the crawler visited in an object. This is a tiny memory leak on its own but insignificant. The strange thing is that the string is somehow related to the whole HTML object and keeps reference to it. I have to add a character to it and than remove it to destroy the reference. The typeof(string) is string not object so I'm surprised that any references are maintained. Anyway... thank you for help.

Comment: Hey @LukaszKujawa, that is a really interesting find. Can you provide information on how you tested for this or discovered this? Is there a spot in the code of node-web-crawler where you incorporated this fix?